ASP.NET Core Docker images update schedule
General question about ASP.NET Core lifecycle. For context:  I am trying to understand/predict what the maintenance cycle would be for a dockerized application that uses Microsoft ASP.NET Core Docker containers.
Example, in my dockerfile, I have
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0

If I understand correctly, every time I rebuild the Docker container, it checks for latest/pulls latest ASP.NET Core 8.0 from Microsoft's container registry.
If true, then my question is, how often will the underlying .NET /ASP.NET Core image be updated by Microsoft, and what do I have to do to keep current with latest builds and to make sure prod version is always up to date? Does "long term support" imply that MS will keep providing updates and vulnerability fixes?

"Standard support" for the odd numbered versions (like the upcoming .NET 9) means support for 18 months after release; "Long Term Support" for the even-numbered versions (like the current .NET 8) means support for 36 months after release. That's currently a fact of life. But how many times the Docker images will be updated with minor / bugfix versions, is harder to predict - typically monthly

Docker will not pull a new image automatically if one exist locally when building. To get it to do that, you need to add the --pull option on docker build.
